# @DataJpaTest saving entity using repository, can't retrieve the data using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am migrating from spring-boot 1.5.x to 2.0.4 and noticed an interesting case/behaviour with @DataJpaTest

I have a test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;


    @Test
    public void save() {

        String number = "123";

        SomeEntity entity = SomeEntity.builder()
                .number(number)
                //some attributes here
                .build();

        repository.save(entity);


//that line fails because SELECT returns nothing back
        Map<String, Object> result = template.queryForMap("select id, version from some_entity where number=?", number);

}
```

This test above fails because nothing is returned from the template. I can't see even INSERT statement fired in the logs. 
But with old version of spring-boot of 1.5.x I can see the INSERT been fired and test passes.

But the interesting thing with upgraded version is if I add a line `repository.findAll` (not `repository.findById(id)` -> that one won't help)  before `repository.save(entity)` it all works good and in the logs, I can see and INSERT statement fired.

Can someone please help me to understand what's going on and how it works under the hood.
Why the entity has not been persisted? and why `repository.findAll` is so special that makes it to persist the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because findAll method triggers flush of all changes from memory(persistence context) to database.

You can see in my screen the place where it all happens:
[image]

There is also a corresponding method in JpaRepository:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--
It may be used to flush changes immediately.

Additionally, you may use saveAndFlush method:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-

Comment: hi, why when I downgrade spring-boot back to 1.5.x  the test passes and INSERT is logged  without changing any code.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because JPA does not flush immediately after `save(entity)`. This means that the JdbcTemplate would not be able to retreive what you saved using JPA without the **flush**. So you could use the `repository.saveAndFlush(entity)` to make saved data available immediately for jdbcTemplate.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;


    @Test
    public void save() {

        String number = "123";

        SomeEntity entity = SomeEntity.builder()
            .number(number)
            //some attributes here
            .build();

        repository.saveAndFlush(entity);


        //that line fails because SELECT returns nothing back
        Map<String, Object> result = template.queryForMap("select id, version from some_entity where number=?", number);

}
```